# I'd like to hide (not disable) 'protect workbook' from the review tab in command bar Excel (customUI)

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Hi I'd like to hide the protect workbook button in the Excel ribbon (in the review  tab). I know this is possible by implementing a customUI. (As explained on http://www.rondebruin.nl/ )

I already found the idMso for this button and managed to disable it.

idMso: ReviewRestrictEditing

I had no succes in my attempts for hinding the button from the ribbon. This is what I have so far:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">     
<ribbon>

<tabs>

<tab idMso="TabReview" >
<group idMso="?????????????" >
    <button idMso="ReviewRestrictEditing" visible = "false" /> 
</group>
</tab>

</tabs>

</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

How can I find the group idMso? I went over a list for excel 2007, but haven't found the correct id yet.

Comment: Have you tried `GroupChangesExcel`? This might only be for 2010 or later.....

Answer (score 3):

Did you read Ron's article on how to [Change built-in groups in the Ribbon in Excel 2007-2016](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win016.htm)

> It is not possible to add to or remove controls from built-in groups in the Ribbon. For example, the Format Painter button from the Home tab's Clipboard group cannot be removed from this group.
>
> But there is a way around this restriction. We can hide a built-in group and then duplicate it with RibbonX. And then we can modify our duplicate group anyway we want.

**Question is what version of Excel are you using?**

**There are sample files for 2007/2010 & 2016 that replace all groups**

You can also find a list of the idMso values for Excel 2007 [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909393(v=office.12).aspx) and
a Word document with the idMso values for Excel 2007 - 2013 [[MS-CUSTOMUI]-160715](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-CUSTOMUI/%5BMS-CUSTOMUI%5D-160715.docx)

Since I wanted to test it myself, I might as well share what I came up with (it's different from what is in the sample files, since I'm using Excel 2013 and Ron doesn't have it available)

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon> 
<tabs>

<!-- Set visible to false for the Changes group on the Review tab-->
<tab idMso="TabReview"> 
<group idMso="GroupChangesExcel" visible="false"/>  
</tab>


<!-- Point to the Built-in tab to the ribbon -->
<tab idMso="TabReview"> 

<!-- Add Changes group -->
<group id="DupChanges" label="Changes" insertBeforeMso="GroupChangesExcel" >    
    <button idMso="SheetProtect" size="large"/> 
    <!-- button idMso="ReviewProtectWorkbook" size="large" / --> 
    <button idMso="ReviewShareWorkbook" size="large"/>

    <button idMso="ReviewProtectAndShareWorkbook" />
    <button idMso="ReviewAllowUsersToEditRanges" />
    <menu idMso="ReviewTrackChangesMenu" />
</group> 

</tab>


</tabs> 
</ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

Depending on which CUI file `customUI.xml` (2007) vs `customUI14.xml` (2010) the `idMso` may change, which happens to be the case for the `Protect Workbook` button your asking about.  I just stick to the 2007, since I haven't had a need for any Backstage stuff yet.