# disable connection and query ribbon by vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that makes several queries to other excel files and to a SQL server using PowerQwery.

I want to prevent users from accessing or editing/deleting the query.

**How can I prevent access or disable connection and query ribbon with VBA Code *in an unprotected file***

I know it is possible by protecting the file, but I would like to check how this can be done in an unprotected file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To hide the "Queries and Connections" section from the ribbon, you could use a Custom UI XML file and add it to your Excel file (more details on how to do that in [this article](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm)).

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I'm using Excel 365, so the following worked for me:

[FileName: customUI14.xml]

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>

            <!-- Set visible to false for the Queries and Connections on the Data tab-->
            <tab idMso="TabData">
                <group idMso="GroupDataQueriesAndConnectionsWorkbookLinks" visible="false"/>
            </tab>

            <tab idMso="TabData">

                <!-- Replace the group with an empty one -->
                <group id="DupGroupDataQueriesAndConnectionsWorkbookLinks" label="Queries &amp;&amp; Connections" insertBeforeMso="GroupDataQueriesAndConnectionsWorkbookLinks">

                </group>

            </tab>

        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

This code is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730713/5958842), but I've left the group empty since we don't want any buttons there.

If you are using a different version of Excel, you might need to replace `GroupDataQueriesAndConnectionsWorkbookLinks` with a different group name. Note that you can find a list of the official group names in this repository:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers
(Select the folder corresponding to your version of Excel and download the file excelcontrols.xlsx).

Comment: Note that there is also the option to just use the [QueryTable.BeforeRefresh event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.beforerefresh) and set `Cancel = true` to prevent the refresh. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732566/5958842) explains how you could go about it.